# haskell BinaryTree signatur termalalgebra calculate size

Tags: haskell, tree

I need to write a function in haskell that calculates the size of the binary Tree. I have an attemp, but don't get what the error message tells me or whats wrong.

My attemp:

```
sizeBintree :: Bintree a -> Int 
sizeBintree  = foldBin $ BinSig {empty_ = 0, 
                              fork = \a left right -> a+sizeBintree left+sizeBintree right}
```

the relevant definitions:

```
data Bintree a = Empty | Fork a (Bintree a) (Bintree a)

data BinSig a val = BinSig {empty_ :: val,
                            fork :: a -> val -> val -> val}
foldBin:: BinSig a val -> Bintree a -> val
foldBin alg Empty = empty_ alg
foldBin alg (Fork a left right) = fork alg a (foldBin alg left)
                                             (foldBin alg right)
```

the error message:

```
Couldn't match expected type 'Bintree a0' with actual type 'Int' 
In the expression: a+sizeBintree left+sizeBintree right 
In the 'fork'    field of a record 
In the second argument of '($)', namely 'BinSig {empty_ = 0,fork = \a left right -> a+sizeBintree left+sizeBintree right}' 
relevant bindings include 
right::Bintree a0 
left:: Bintree a0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want your `fork` to be this:

```
fork = \a left right -> 1 + left + right
```

There were two problems with your version. First you are calculating size, not adding up the elements of the tree. So you do not want to add that `a`, it might not even be something you can add at all.

```
 fork = \a left right -> a+sizeBintree left+sizeBintree right
                         ^
```

Secondly look at the type of fork,

```
 fork :: a -> val -> val -> val
```

it takes an element of the tree, then two values (not trees!) and returns another value. Those two values are going to be the results for the folding of the left and right subtrees.

```
 fork = \a left right -> a+sizeBintree left+sizeBintree right
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Note fork isn't supposed to perform any recursion. The recursion scheme is defined by `foldBin`.

Comment: Oh yes, of course. Got a little confused about  size and sum `:-) . Thank you very much! I think i understood it!